how should i analyze panel data if all units are treated simultaneously?
I possess a dataset of 273 companies from the time period 2001-2017, and i want to study whether the effect of the policy (that was implemented in 2009) on profit was moderated by industry type.
My problem is that the policy was nationally implemented, and all the companies are from the same country. this means that from the period up untill 2009 i have zero treated units while after 2008 all my units are treated.
My first thought would be using a entity fixed effects model with an interactive term. However, im quit new to fixed effects models, and im pretty unsure on how to deal with the whole simultaneous treatment of the companies.
Have i misunderstood something about fixed effects model, or are they applicable in my situation?

Welcome. You may find my response here somewhat helpful.

Thanks Thomas. It was very helpful.
